# Обход Bitmap по пиксельно

Tags: c++, bitmap

```
 HDC     hScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC     hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreen);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreen, abs(b.x - a.x), abs(b.y - a.y));
    HGDIOBJ old_obj = SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);
    BOOL    bRet = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, abs(b.x - a.x), abs(b.y - a.y), hScreen, a.x, a.y, SRCCOPY);
```

Есть такой код сохранения скриншота.
Есть битмап и хотелось бы обойти его в цикле попиксельно.
как то так.

```
for(int x = 0, y = 0; x < hBitmap.Width, y < hBitmap.Height; y++, x++ ) 
{
   auto color = GetPixel(x, y);
}
```

но как преоброзовать его в тип  котолрый котоырй можно обюработать циклом не понимаю

как это правильно  сделать.

Comment: цикл в цикле, abs(b.x - a.x) - ширина, abs(b.y - a.y) - высота вашего битмапа

Comment: это да.  это я понимаю. просто как сам битмап перебрать. не понятно

Comment: а, тогда вам вот это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688409/getdibits-and-loop-through-pixels-using-x-y